# Websocket connection fails for internal communication within a Kubernetes container

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, kubernetes, websocket

I am using Kubernetes to deploy my React Application. Due to the database, I am using (RethinkDB). I have to initiate a WebSocket connection between my React Application and a Node.js server that proxies to the Database instance. The connection works as intended when I deploy the Database instance, backend Node server and the react application in my local machine. However when I deploy the application in Kubernetes I receive the error

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8015/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

within my react application.

For further debugging, I executed a terminal within the container and ran curl command to the Service that connects to the Database and received no errors. I also ran the backend node server to see whether it connects to the remote database and saw no issues there. Finally, I tested whether the Backend server initiates the WebSocket as intended using wscat and the WebSocket connection is working. And due to the fact that the application runs well on my local machine, leads me to believe that there the issue in the React Application connecting to the WebSocket could be caused by how Kubernetes handles Websocket connections. Any clarification on the issue is gladly appreciated.

P.S

I Have added the backend server code, the code within the React application that connects to the WebSocket and the YAML files of my React+Backend Deployment. If any more files are required please feel free to comment

backend node server

```
const http = require('http');
var rethinkdbWebsocketServer = require('rethinkdb-websocket-server');

const httpServer = http.createServer();
rethinkdbWebsocketServer.listen({
    httpServer: httpServer,
    httpPath: '/',
    dbHost: remoteDB_IP,
    dbPort: 28015,
    unsafelyAllowAnyQuery: true
});

httpServer.listen(8015);
```

React code that connects to the Websocket

```
ReactRethinkdb.DefaultSession.connect({
  host: 'localhost',          // the websocket server
  port: process.env.REACT_APP_WEBSOCKET_PORT,
  path: '/',
  secure: false,
  autoReconnectDelayMs: 2000, // when disconnected, millis to wait before reconnect
});
```

deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: dashboard
  labels:
    app: dashboard
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: dashboard
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: dashboard
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: dashboard
        image: myrepor/dashbaord
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        env:
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: dashboard
spec:
  selector:
    app: dashboard
  ports:
    - port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Comment: where in kubernetes is the database deployed? not in the same Pod?

Comment: It is deployed as another kubernetes pod and is exposed using a loadbalancer

Comment: but then the address to the database is **not**  `localhost`

Answer (score 0):

so kubernetes ideas is all about running each application in separate pod.

And connecting them through services.

This way you can deploy each layer separately without down time - service routes to old pod(s) until new are up and running. (and even more important scale up the separately )
Kubernetes does some kind of name resolution inside of each k8s cluster. Not exactly sure if that is a full dns or not

thus I would recommend

- separate your node server into one pod. and deploy service for it with your ws port (8015).
- your react app separate pod with its own service and define node server service name as endpoint for WS.

The reason is simple - not even sure that localhost going to be resolved correctly with in the pod.

Comment: I implemented your solution by deploying the applications and backend on their own pods to no avail. However, in my first try, I did this by exposing the WebSocket as a ClusterIP. In my second try, I went with the same approach but exposed my WebSocket to external traffic using a LoadBalancer and that approach worked. I do not completely know why it worked so I will leave the question unanswered for now, for someone with a better understanding, to answer the question